# document.ready not working on linking a page through ahref

Tags: jquery, document-ready

The document only loads when the page is hit directly with its url, it does not work if the page is loaded through an ahref link.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
alert( "document loaded" );
});
```

I know this has been asked before and I tried a few things and nothing worked. The window also does not get loaded on opening a page through a link

```
$( window ).on( "load", function() {
  alert( "window loaded" );
});
```

I also tried `pageinit`, not sure if I used it wrong but it did not work.
Any help will be appreciated

Also, I am using rails

My application

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <title>DevPortal</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I link my one page to another using the following code snippet:

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="new_page">
    My link
 </a>
</p>
```

Comment: Open your console, does it say anything?

Comment: Can you recreate the issue starting with an empty 'project'?   ie a simple html page, jquery and a doc ready.  It's likely you have some other code acting on the anchor

Comment: Are your pages loaded through Ajax ?

Comment: Also in the console, enable 'preserve log' (or whatever it's called in your browser, that's for Chrome).

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I am not using Ajax

Comment: @Jorden1337 console does not show anything, `document is ready` is not displayed on opening a page through a link

Comment: *"I am not using Ajax"* I don't think that is correct.

Comment: @slal paste the ahref link on which you click

Comment: The only difference between loading a page by typing the URL into the address bar and clicking on a link with that same URL is that the link will send a `Referer` header. That shouldn't affect your Javascript.

Comment: Are you sure you're reloading the page with the link? If it points to the same URL with a different hash code, it doesn't reload, it just scrolls to that element.

Comment: I have edited the above question to add more details

Comment: @Barmar That is one possibility, because I think its not getting reloaded, if it is how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me as I was using turbolinks

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
   alert("It works");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If the link points to a hash ID in the same URL, it won't reload the page. Use the `hashchange` event instead.

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function() {
    alert("hash changed do something");
});
```